# How to get accessibility focused current item Android

Tags: android, android-layout, accessibility

I am working with android accessibility. For my requirement i have to get accessibility currently focussed item. i.e. Currently highlighted item in screen.

Something like

```
if(myButton.isHighlighted)
{
}
```

I tried all below but nothing workout for me...

```
if(mybutton.isFocused())
if(mybutton.isSelected())
if(mybutton.isAccessibilityFocused())
if(mybutton.isEnabled())
if(mybutton.isActivated())
if(mybutton.isFocusable())
if(mybutton.isPressed())
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can call [isAccessibilityFocused](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfo#isAccessibilityFocused())

Answer (score -2):

try these attributes on Button in the layout

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

and must call inside java file:

```
mybutton.requestFocus();
```

After this check, if button is focused with accessibility.

Comment: Thanks for your answer... But your code is to make a item to focusable. Am asking to get the currently focused item.